# What does the number below the clan-logo mean?

Tags: dota-2

Attached is a screenshot from the latest major. There is a numerical value presented below one of the clan flags (the side varies). My question is what does the number represent?

[image: Screenshot from game]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the *fan level* (as the Wiki calls it) of the team.

I found a few Reddits asking about this.  [This one](https://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/1jni7v/dont_upvote_what_is_the_number_under_teams_logo/) states:

> [The] Amount of pennants level equipped of spectators in Dota TV. Basically every lvl 1 pennant adds 1 to the number, and lvl 2 pennants adds 2 to the number.

[This Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/1z117r/can_anybody_tell_me_what_the_number_under_the/) says the same thing basically (with reference to Na'Vi):

> It's the number of spectators in the DotA2 client who have a Na'Vi team pennant.

The Dota 2 Wiki calls this number the *Fan Level* on the [pennants page](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Pennant):

> Pennants are equippable items that allow users to show support for a team during tournaments, by increasing a team's Fan Level - visible in-game to other DotaTV users.

Answer (score 0):

Those are pennants: They used to be sold on the Dota Store, and it was a way to cheer for your team, there are different levels to existing pennants and the level just multiplies how much a pennant is worth (pennant lvl 1 adds 1).

Iirc you can not buy pennants anymore, and even if you can, there are no pennants for new-ish teams.